# ipa failed to sync from itunes to device

Tags: ios, xcode, installation

when i try to install through xcode directly app will install in the device.
when i try to sync ipa  or app file sync from itunes .app is not install in the device.instead of install the app status will be 'will install'

i am not understood .is it any certificate issue?

i have attached image file link for detail understanding

https://skydrive.live.com/?cid=eb7f2f7c40e359ee#cid=EB7F2F7C40E359EE&id=EB7F2F7C40E359EE!499

Answer (score 2):

try to install the ipa with the iPhone configuration utility

http://support.apple.com/kb/dl1465

Comment: thanks a lot...the app is installing now.but why its not install normally through itunes that is why i am wondering...

Comment: is it any difference between installing via iTunes and iPhone configuration utility.

Comment: Same problem.  Configuration Utility will install it but iTunes sits at "will install"

Comment: Check your certificate with which you have signed your ipa. Usually the IPCU doesn't let you install because the profile is not the same.

Answer (score 0):

Click on the iTunes bottom **Apply/Sync** button .

**Step1**:Click **Install** button(s) for the application(s) that you need to Sync (status will change to "will install")

**Step2**: Click **Apply/Sync**.

Thats it.

Comment: i did what u said exactly but it wont work out.after click the apply button status will be automatically changed the state sync...

Comment: is it any certificate problem?

Comment: yeah but when i click sync button it will switched to apply button without any changes in app list in devices..

Comment: did u delete the old app (the one u installed via Xcode) ? is same app available in device ? Please delete the app and try again..

Comment: i did before before couple of months back.it wont work out.is any certificate problem?

Comment: even i delete the app and  certifate too.then i restart the device also...nothing will happen...